# React Multiline MUI Text Box Not Displaying the Expected Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a React application where I need to use a multiline text box to edit a job advertisement. The text box should display a default value that includes placeholders which can be dynamically replaced, like `[displayTitle]`, `[minimumMonthlySalaryBeforeTax]`, etc.

However, I've encountered an issue where the text box does not display the expected values as defined in my component's state, despite the state being set correctly with the default text including placeholders.

Here's a simplified version of my component:

```
// ... React and Material-UI imports ...

const defaultAdText = `We have just posted a new vacancy!

// ... Default ad text with placeholders ...

`;

const EditAdDialog = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  const [adText, setAdText] = useState(defaultAdText);
  
  // ... other hooks and functions ...

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      {/* ... other dialog components ... */}
      <TextField
        id="ad-text"
        // ... other TextField props ...
        value={adText}
        onChange={(e) => setAdText(e.target.value)}
      />
      {/* ... other dialog components ... */}
    </Dialog>
  );
};

// ... PropTypes and export ...
```

Relevant Package.json libraries:

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
"@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
"@mui/styles": "^5.13.2",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.7.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid-generator": "^6.7.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^6.7.0",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.2",
"@mui/x-license-pro": "^6.6.0",
"@sentry/nextjs": "^7.80.0",
"@types/material-ui": "^0.21.12",
```

I expect the text area to show the default ad text when the dialog opens, but instead, it is empty as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: Image of problem]

Even adding height `300px` to the styling doesn't fix the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `key` prop to force the component to re-render when adText changed.

Comment: Added to the question, thanks to answering. The default value is supposed to only be used when the the component is not controlled. I am controlling the state via `useState`, and thus it is controlled, which is why I believe the value field is necessary. [MUI Default Value](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#TextField-prop-defaultValue)

Comment: Oh really, then please update the key of the element after default value change.

Comment: The key prop did not work, so now I am thinking it is a caching issue, as it works on localhost, and incognito.